# Why can't the first argument in sprintf be a char pointer in C

Tags: c

I want to convert an integer to a string. Here's what works:

```
int main() {
    int a= 54734;
    char a_str[10];
    sprintf(a_str, "%d", a);

    printf("%s\n", a_str);
    return 0;
}
```

But this does not work:

```
int main() {
    int a= 54734;
    char* a_str;

    sprintf(a_str, "%d", a);

    printf("%s\n", a_str);

    return 0;
}
```

It returns:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: 
SIGSEGV)
```

I thought string is null terminated, so a pointer to char should work as well. Because I'm new to C, so please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: char* a_str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*21);

Comment: you need tell system how many memory you need,thats how the computer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an important thing to understand is that a segmentation fault usually occurs when your program attempts to use memory that it is not allowed to use.

Second, you have to understand what `sprintf` is doing. When you call `sprintf(a_str, "%d", a)`, you are moving the contents of variable `a` to the memory space **at the address pointed to by `a_str`**. Therefore, in order to not cause a segmentation fault, your program must "own" the memory pointed to by `a_str` before using it in `sprintf`.

When you pass `char a_str[10]` into `sprintf`, it always works because the program has allocated its own memory space for `a_str` (with the line `char a_str[10];`). Therefore, when you use `sprintf` on it, the program is accessing memory it's allowed to access.

However, when you pass your `char* a_str` into `sprintf`, you are causing undefined behavior. When you created the `char* a_str`, all you did was create a `char` **pointer** that points to some random location in memory; your program most likely does not have access to the memory at the location pointed to by this random pointer. Therefore, calling `sprintf` and attempting to move the contents of `a` into that will throw a segmentation fault. This would be solved if you pointed your `char* a_str` at some usable memory location using something like `malloc`.

Comment: Another note because of the wording of your question title: both of the things you passed into `sprintf` (both `char a_str[10]` and `char* a_str`) are "`char` pointers". All an array is in C/C++ is a pointer to the first item in that array.

Comment: Array decays to pointer in some situations but generally speaking array and pointer aren't the same, although they share some similarities

Comment: Thanks @qrdl, I over-generalized. `sprintf` will specifically treat a `char[]` as a `char*` because `sprintf` expects a `char*` and so the array will be implicitly converted to a pointer